# How to print parse Json using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

How do I print using grep awk just to print success from the below string.

{"identity":"2320147","authentication":"success"}

Comment: It looks like it's easier to parse using python or other tools than shell commands. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/5666087

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU awk`:

`echo "{"identity":"2320147","authentication":"success"}" |awk -F "[:}]" '{print $3}'`

Output:

`success`

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq`

```
test='{"identity":"2320147","authentication":"success"}'

$ jq -r '.authentication' <<< $test
success
```

JQ's help

```
$ jq -h
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
...
     -r     output raw strings, not JSON texts;
...
```